# laravel 5.1 routes groups takes only the first controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {

    Route::controller(null, 'BoxController');
    Route::controller(null, 'CostController');

});
```

This is a routed group in Laravel 5.1 the urls for the first controller is working but not for the second one `'CostController'`.

If I switch the lines the first one works only. I want both controllers url to be prefixed with `...api/box/` and `...api/cost/`

### Examples on the internet has only one controller in the group, maybe there is another syntax?

**I want the urls like : ( because I work on REST application)**

```
api/cost
api/box
```

not like:

```
api/cost/cost
api/box/box
```

Comment: Are you passing `null` as URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `null` for route?

If you'll use different routes, both will work:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {

    Route::controller('box', 'BoxController');
    Route::controller('cost', 'CostController');

});
```

Comment: I passed null for the routes because I want the urls like:

api/cost
api/box

if I add them it works but the url will be like this : 

api/cost/cost
api/box/cost

Comment: But route can't be null. What exactly URL you want to use?

Comment: I have update the question above would you check how I would like them. ;*)

Comment: Thanks for update, now it's clear for me. So, just use the code from my example, in that case your URLs like `api/cost` will work just fine.

Comment: Thank for everything, But it dosent work I have to write the full path which is bot practical I think, I have to write like: api/box/box ;-(

Comment: Do you have actions called `getBox`? If so, try to use: `Route::get('box', 'BoxController@getBox');`

Comment: `Route::get('box', 'BoxController@getBox');` should really work for `/api/box`, try it.

Comment: Thanks very much! it works. in this case I have to add for all actions, but its okay.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Passing null as route is one thing but the main culprit is that you are passing the same route for different controllers. The solution is to use real routes for the controllers, so. i.e. `box` for `BoxController` and `cost` for the other. It will work correctly then

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::controller('box', 'BoxController');
    Route::controller('cost', 'CostController');
});
```